# How to affix a pound sign (£) to decimal (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, sorting, decimal, currency

Initially there was an issue of lexicographic-ordering which caused a column of currency values to be sorted as string.

In order to sort a column of values within VB as currency this following code is utilised: `m_dtTemp.Columns("P/O Value").DataType = GetType(Decimal)`
which works absolutely fine, the problem now is the lack of pound sign (£) affixed to the values.

I can't see a method to include a pound sign without resorting back to type string, thus taking me back to square one. The overall goal is to retain the numerical sort functionality whilst an addition of a pound sign is affixed to the values.

Comment: You need to say what technology you re using : asp.net, asp.net mvc,winforms , wpf or something else. And may be show more code ! Essential for making a good question and being hepled

Comment: Can you just put £ in your column header, so it's implied that every number in that column is in pounds?

Comment: I would show more code, but unfortunately it is against my companies policy. Apologies for not mentioning earlier, It's a windows form application. I'm new to stack overflow so still learning the best approach to question asking.

Comment: like InbetweenWeekends said - If you dont want to resort to strings and or you would like to do data manilpulation later, put the pound sign in your column header.

Comment: Yeah thanks InbetweenWeekends, pretty much what I've done for the time being. My supervisor will just have to make do with the compromise for now.